# Can i make assignment operator to work like copy constructor?

Tags: c++

Hello i got a class which looks like this:

```
class myClass{
public:
 //other consturctors

 //copy constructor:
 myClass (const myClass & x)
 : C1(x.C1), C2(x.C2), C3(x.C3), S1(x.S1) {};

 //other functions

 myClass & operator = (const myClass & x);

private:
 const otherClass1 C1;
 const otherClass2 C2;
 const otherClass3 * C3;
 string S1;
}
```

and I my problem is with assingment operator, because the compiler doesnt allow me to do it like in copy constructor. Thats problem because classes i need to assign doesnt have assign operator implemented and i cant edit them so I cant just do it like this:

```
myClass & operator = (const myClass & x) {
 C1=x.C1; // -> compile error
 C2=x.C2; // -> compile error
 C3=x.C3;
 S1=x.S1;
 return *this;
}
```

So I've tried to implement the assign operator like:

```
myClass & operator = (const myClass & x) {
 static myClass tmp(x);
 return tmp;
}
```

althoght its working a little bit, I think its causing some problems in my program especially inserting to vector of myClasses doesnt work very well.

Could you guys give me advice how to correctly make assign operator to work like I need ? (remove old myClass and make myClass(copy) istead of old one, or somehow assign classes with this syntax :C1(copy.C1) ... {} ) ?

**EDIT: Removing const from C1 and C2 seems to be solution to my problem.**

Comment: Your class has `const` data members. So assignment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need assignment?

Comment: You mean I dont need assign operator? I thought that aswell, but Im getting a compile error while trying to insert into vector of myClasses without assign operator.

Comment: All your problems are because those members are const, so they can't be assigned to.

Comment: Well, depending on whether you're using C++11, it has to be move assignable or copy assignable to go in vector. If you have constant members, you can't make that work.

Comment: juanchopanza has a valid point about the const data members. Also, copying the C3 pointer ooks dangerous, after assignment the two objects will have a pointer to the same otherclass3 instance. Who owns it, and who will delete it?

Comment: Im not using C++11, so you think i might made it work only when i remove const from my class members? Copying C3 should be ok.

Comment: The last code with the static tmp var looks to be plain wrong. You are not changing the this pointer at all, so there is no assignment. The return value is only needed for method chaining (in this case it's an operator, but the principle is the same. When you use 'a = b = c' it's the return value of b's operator= that is used as parameter to a's operator =.)

Comment: so i have to change the this pointer to point at tmp. I thought of that before but I didnt really find out how to do that. I tried this=&tmp and &(*this)=&tmp but noone of these gets compiled. Also dont I need to delete old this or something like that while changing the pointer?

Comment: You can't change the this pointer.

Comment: Thx for advices. Removing const from C1 and C2 fixed my problem, now I dont even need to implement assign operator, since it can use default now for vector myClass insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the 3rd piece of code with the static, you should try to get the second block of code working, and resolve the 2 compile errors.

If removing the constness does not work, you can store C1 and C2 on the heap.

```
const otherClass1 * C1;
const otherClass2 * C2;
```

Change them to pointers and new/delete them where needed, so you can use the copy constructor with a new, instead of the assignment operator (which you say does not exist for those classes)

Answer (score 1):

you have const data members so you can't change them in assignment operator.
other noticeable thing is that you are doing shallow copy in your copy constructor, which you should avoid. you are only copying address in one pointer to another, it means both pointers will point to same address and if later on one deletes it, an other will become dangling pointer.